# Programmatically close browser tab with no Java History using HTML

Tags: javascript, email, browser

Trying to achieve what should be a simple thing:

Backstory:

I operate a popular news website. Every morning we send out a 'News Update Email' to several thousand subscribers.

That news update contains links from a news story summaries contained within the subscribers 'News Update Email' to a full news stories contained on our news website.

Each website full news story contains a Java history 'Back' button which, when the page is accessed from within the website, returns the reader to their previous page.

All good - EXCEPT - when the page is access from a subscribers 'News Update Email' - As there is no 'Previous Page' in Java History, so when the user clicks the 'Back' button (Expecting to be returned to their Email program) - NOTHING HAPPENS - Because Java History is empty.

We continually get messages from Users saying 'Your news story page is not working --- Blar, Blar'

So, what I need to do is find a way to programically close the tab that contains that website news page when its 'Back' button is clicked IF that tab's Java history is empty, else 'Go Back' as normal if Java History not empty.

I KNOW you can only programmically close a tab with Java which has been opened with Java, and therein lies the problem - Email clients don't tend to allow java in HTML emails, so I can't use Java to open a tab & am therefore stuck with .

Example link in Email : button

THEN - Close that tab from within itself:

example 'Back' button in website News Story: Back

Putting aside the need for code to determine if Java History is empty, will the above work on all browsers - or not ??? Or is there a better way???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be confusing [tag:java] and [tag:javascript]; they are completely different programming languages.

Comment: Maybe check  `History.length` and go back if not 0 or `window.close()` otherwise.

Comment: Hi  Quentin - Sorry my bad. meant JavaScript - Just realised StackOverflow has cut my code snippets out of my post !! Not worried about the History function, just the logic - Can a browser Tab opened with an <a> link click in an Email be closed from within itself using an <a> command - or not?   Can't use JavaScript to close Browser Tab because can't open that browser Tab from email using JavaScript.